# What is the proper way to manage large IStreams?

Tags: c#, com, interop, stream

I am writing a C# class library to transfer large volumes of data through COM automation using an IStream.  It uses the [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378980%28VS.85%29.aspx) API call to create the stream, and the methods within [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMTypes.IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.istream.aspx) to work with it.

My question is, when transferring large volumes of data, what is the best way to keep the memory footprint under control?  Loading 100MB+ of file data into memory seems wasteful, and the client application would need to wait until that process is complete before downloading anything.

My plan was to create a reasonably sized stream and write to it multiple times.  Before writing the next chunk of data, Seek back to the beginning and overwrite starting at the beginning.  Am I going about this the right way, and is there a better method to solve this problem?

Comment: Where does the data come from?  It is rare to have to store *everything* in memory.  You can surely just trickle-read it in the Read() method implementation?

Comment: From a variety of sources including db tables and text files.  Library code parses the data into a byte array and transfers it to the stream.  I can write read/write it in small chunks, that's not a problem.  The issue is, as I keep writing to the end of the stream it will continuously grow, right?

Comment: You are probably best writing your own class which implements the IStream interface, then you can handle calls to the Read method and load data on demand, once it has been read there is no need to maintain that data anymore (assuming you are not allowing the IStream to be seekable).

Comment: Is this question based on experience or just the fear of bad things happening?  We have a logger that passes data interprocess via iStreams.  The data transferred is bigger than memory (though not on the ratio you are suggesting) and it just works out.  I suspect the sending process just blocks until the receiver picks  up the data.  We never really got around to asking your question because it just worked and nobody thought to ask.

Comment: Why do you have COM automation in a C# picture? Is it because you have some legacy component to talk to?

Comment: @Frank: Interesting, I will try streaming a large file without resetting my position and see if it can handle it.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: It is exchanging large volumes of data with a Dynamics NAV client.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a file created with the attributes FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY and FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE. Write you stuff in there. Windows will try to keep it in the disk cache unless memory runs out. It will self-destruct when you close the handle or when your program terminates (or crashes!). I learned about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/04/19/116084.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For temporary local storage of large amounts of data a memory mapped file is usually a good idea. It hands over the memory management responsibility to Windows which knows best how to do it. If you don't specify a file it will map into the paging file and never go to the physical disk unless it becomes necessary.

If you are using .NET 4.0 you got a [managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to memory mapped files.

Answer (score 0):

Every stream implementation realies on buffer. Most of the time you will have 100% control over the buffer size. You can adjust buffer size to tune for performance vs. memory use balance. If you are not opening hundreds of stream at the same time I suggest be generous stream size as large as possible:

> var readStream=new
>   System.IO.File.OpenRead(sourceFilePath);
>   var writeStream=new
>   System.Io.File.Create(destinationFile);
>
> byte[] buffer=new bytes[**bufferSize**];
>   int readLength;
>   while((readLength=readStream.Read(0,0,**bufferSize**))>0)
>   {
>   writeStream.Write(buffer,0,readLength);
>   }
>
> writeStream.Close();
>   readStream.Close();

Answer (score 0):

When sending large messages using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), it is often desirable to limit the amount of memory used to buffer those messages. One possible solution is to stream the message body (assuming the bulk of the data is in the body). However some protocols require buffering of the entire message. Reliable messaging and security are two such examples.

> Another possible solution is to divide up the large message into smaller messages called chunks, send those chunks one chunk at a time, and reconstitute the large message on the receiving side. The application itself could do this chunking and de-chunking or it could use a custom channel to do it. The chunking channel sample shows how a custom protocol or layered channel can be used to do chunking and de-chunking of arbitrarily large messages.

Sample provided download available
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx